# LIBGDX: How can i tell when a sound has finished playing?

Tags: libgdx

The Sound API seems to be missing a function to indicate that a sound is finished playing. Is there some other way of finding out if the sound is done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not without submitting a patch to libgdx as far as I know the underlying Sound Backends for both OpenAL and Android don't even track the information internally, though the Music API has an isPlaying() function and getPosition() function as per the [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html).

Comment: This was brought up in the latest libGDX hangout too (confirming that there is no API ATM): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ppr7QPeMlMo.  I believe the work-around mentioned in the video is knowing how long your audio runs...

Comment: I resolved on two things, making the sounds more acceptable to play overlapped, and saving the last play time and play length. I still love libgdx notwithstanding.

Comment: @P.T. That's not a workaround for being able to 'tell when the sound is finished'...it's the opposite. That's the only thing you can do if you don't have that function at all, which is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

just set this

```
sound.setLooping(false);
```

this way it will not run again and again.

and to check whether sound is playing or
not do this.

make a boolean variable

```
boolean soundplaying;
```

in render method do this

```
if(sound.isPlaying()){
soundplaying =true
}
```

and  make a log

```
gdx.app.log("","sound"+soundplaying);
```

Comment: I think this answer is correct. Just instead of `Sound` class use `Music` class and it got all you want - use `isPlaying()` or `setOnCompletionListener(..)` and `OnCompletionListener`.

Answer (score -1):

You can track this by storing the sound instance id that e.g. `play()` and `loop()` return. Example code:

```
private Sound sound;
private Long soundId;

...

public void startSound()  {
    if (soundId != null) {
        return;
    }
    soundId = sound.loop();   // or sound.play()
}

public void stopSound() {
    sound.stop(soundId);
    soundId = null;
}
```

If you didn't want to have to call `stopSound()` from client code, you could just call it from `startSound()` instead of the `return`, to ensure any previous sound is stopped.

Comment: How does this detect if the sound has finished playing? Like if I play a 2 second long dog bark sound, it plays for 2 seconds and then finishes - how does your code indicate that the dog has finished barking?