# How to check if sound has finished playing in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

How can I check if a sound is playing or not in Libgdx?

```
Sound sound; 
sound = assetmanager.get("sound01.wav");
sound.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound does not have that feature, only Music.

You should use a boolean variable to check it.

[LIBGDX: How can i tell when a sound has finished playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704733/libgdx-how-can-i-tell-when-a-sound-has-finished-playing)

Comment: That's too bad, I wanted to use the pitch feature of the Sound class.